# Replicating the Quotation Environment in XeTeX

Tags: xetex, plain-tex, quotation

Our department's template for letters requires that they be compiled using XeTeX. I am writing a letter in which I would like to include an inset quotation. In LaTeX I would write

```
\begin{quotation}
The quoted text
\end{quotation}
```

My thought was to try replacing this with the plain TeX code that sets a quotation, but I'm not sure how to find this.

How can I replicate the `quotation` environment in XeTeX?

**Edit** Minimal working example:

```
\newif\ifuserfont \userfontfalse
\def\SetLetterFont#1{\userfonttrue\font\userfont=#1} % so the user can set it.

\newdimen\indentation \indentation=2em\relax
\newdimen\betweenpar \betweenpar=\medskipamount\relax
\raggedbottom
\interlinepenalty=100
\hsize=6.25 true in
\voffset=24pt
\advance\vsize by -\voffset
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=0pt
\nopagenumbers

\def\beginlinemode{\endmode
    \begingroup\parindent=0pt%
    \obeylines
    \frenchspacing
    \def\endmode{\par\endgroup}}
\def\beginparmode{\endmode
    \begingroup
    \parskip=\betweenpar
    \def\endmode{\par\endgroup}}
\let\endmode=\par
\def\endletter{\endmode\vfill\supereject\end}

\def\body{%
    \ifuserfont\global\userfont\fi
        \global\parindent=\indentation
        \smallskip
        \beginparmode
}%

\def\narrower{%
  \advance\leftskip 1cm
  \advance\rightskip 1cm }

\indentation=0pt

\body


Body text 1,  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

{ \narrower
    Quote paragraph 1, blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 

    Quote paragraph 2 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
}

Body text 2, blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah


\endletter
```

Comment: @Werner Not that I can tell. I see definitions for date, address, opening, body, closing, postscript, and letterhead.

Comment: do they really mandate plain tex rather than mean you should use xelatex??? That makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, it doesn't compile in XeLaTeX.

Comment: @AnnieCarter: It would be better if you could share your letter template, so one can see what works best specific to your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain TeX you can use

```
zzzz

{\narrower
hmmmm zzzzz

}
```

---

The definition of `\narrower` is

```
\def\narrower{%
  \advance\leftskip\parindent
  \advance\rightskip\parindent}
```

you have since clarified that you have `\parindent` set to 0pt so this isn't quite what you want but you can redefine it for example by

```
\def\narrower{%
  \advance\leftskip 2cm
  \advance\rightskip 2cm }
```

To bring the margins in by 2cm or whatever amount you want.

Note that it is very weird to set both `\parindent` and `\parskip` to zero as it makes paragraphs hard (or in some cases impossible) to spot if there is no horizontal or vertical space to mark the start.

```
zzzz
```

Comment: Compiles, but doesn't seem to have any effect in my case.

Comment: @AnnieCarter you had not shown _any_ information about your case. You have now shown that you have the (slightly bizarre) setting of `\parindent` and `\parskip` both zero, as `\narrower` indents by `\parindent` it does nothing here, but it is only a couple of lines, I will add something to my answer.

Comment: @AnnieCarter answer updated

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I thought this would be more trivial than it was (which I guess it would have been if the style file hadn't been redefining things).

Comment: So this new `\narrower` seems to work if my quotation is only one paragraph, but the margins don't persist into a second paragraph. I tried putting a `\narrower` at the beginning of each paragraph, and then the wider margins don't appear at all. (MWE added above.)

Comment: @AnnieCarter in the version you added to the question you have missed out the blank line after the second paragraph so `\narrower` finishes before the second paragraph ends, put a blank line before the `}` as I have in my answer

Comment: Oh man, I never would have figured that out. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can search any of the default document classes and retrieve the definition of the `quotation` environment. See

- [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co):

  ```
  \newenvironment{quotation}
                 {\list{}{\listparindent 1.5em%
                          \itemindent    \listparindent
                          \rightmargin   \leftmargin
                          \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
                  \item\relax}
                 {\endlist}
  ```
- [`report.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls?view=co):

  ```
  \newenvironment{quotation}
                 {\list{}{\listparindent 1.5em%
                          \itemindent    \listparindent
                          \rightmargin   \leftmargin
                          \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
                  \item\relax}
                 {\endlist}
  ```
- [`article.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co):

  ```
  \newenvironment{quotation}
                 {\list{}{\listparindent 1.5em%
                          \itemindent    \listparindent
                          \rightmargin   \leftmargin
                          \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
                  \item\relax}
                 {\endlist}
  ```
- [`letter.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/letter.cls?view=co):

  ```
  \newenvironment{quotation}
                 {\list{}{\setlength\listparindent{1.5em}%
                          \setlength\itemindent{\listparindent}%
                          \setlength\rightmargin{\leftmargin}}%
                  \item[]}
                 {\endlist}
  ```

They're very similar across the classes.

You could also consider using the [`csquotes` package](//ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) which provides a comprehensive set of quotation functionality.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Unfortunately, `\list` returns an undefined control sequence error.

How would I include the `csquotes` package into my XeTeX file? Copy-paste the whole style file into my source?

Comment: @AnnieCarter: You can view [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) and extract any missing content there, including `\list`.

Comment: @Werner really, you can't well you can, but `\list` is so deeply embedded in latex, you would have to include (or be able to remove) dependencies on almost all of latex including the latex output routine